# How to re-enable multiple select picker

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use this bootstrap select picker where multiple values can be selected, by default I want it to be disabled. So in order to enable it a button must be pressed. Problem is that pressing the button will not re-enable this specific field, other fields linked to it work fine.

Anyways the code not working is as follows any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('updateuser')}}">
      @csrf
      <table class="table  table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">User Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Role</th>
            <th scope="col">Sites</th>
            <th scope="col">Created At</th>
            <th scope="col">Updated At</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        @if(count($users)!=0)
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
          <td><input type='text' name="id" placeholder="User ID" value='{{ $user->id }}' readonly></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="name" placeholder="Name" value='{{ $user->name }}' disabled></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="email" placeholder="Email" value='{{ $user->email }}' disabled></td>
          <td><select name="role" disabled>
              <option>none</option>
              <option>Reporter</option>
              <option>Admin</option>
              <option>Super Admin</option>
            </select></td>
          <td><select class="selectpicker selectsite" multiple name="sitesSelected[]" disabled>
              <option selected> {{$site[0]->sitename}}
                < </option>
              <option> {{$site[1]->sitename}} </option>
              <option> {{$site[2]->sitename}} </option>
            </select></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="created_at" placeholder="created_at" value='{{ $user->created_at }}' readonly></td>
          <td><input type='text' name="updated_at" placeholder="updated_at" value='{{ $user->updated_at }}' readonly></td>
          <td><input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
            <input type="submit" name='save' value='save'>
            <button type="button" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" value="{{ $user->id }}">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @endif
      </table>
      {{ $users->links() }}
    </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("form input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true);
     $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){
       $(this).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("disabled",false);
                     
     })
   })
              
 </script>
```

As can be seen in the code, I have constructed a table where each row represents a user of the site. The part that is not working is the selected element named "sitesSelected[]" It won't re-enable when the edit button is pressed however all other elements do re-enable when the edit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know much about Bootstrap, but Multiple selecting functionality is working because of multiple attributes in select elements. (Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp for a better understanding of multiple attr).

So if you want to enable or disable it, you can just remove or add the multiple attributes. Examples below.

To remove the "disabled" attribute to an element:

```
$('select[name="role"]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

To add multiple attributes to element:

```
$(".selectpicker selectsite").attr("multiple","true");
```

To remove multiple attribute to element:

```
$(".selectpicker selectsite").attr("multiple","false");
```

Your question is a little confusing, but I tried my best because I'm also new here and I know how it feels when someone closes your question. Anyway if have doubts, just comment.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, unfortunately I have already tried what you have suggested and pretty much everything I could find on google. Basically the issue I'm having is is by default I want all elements to be disabled and to be re-enabled by pressing the "edit" button. The code I currently have in the script element works for all elements apart from the "sitesSelected" one, not sure if there is something I'm missing but I don't understand why only this element is not affected by the javascript used to re-enale the elements

Comment: I would recommend you to create a test.html file and test your code and if everything is working fine...then the problem is an internal crash, I mean the element is affected by some other js code, maybe a JS file of bootstrap or any other code. may your code is targeting the same element two times due to which it overwrites the first one.

Comment: Create that test.html file and write a raw code without bootstrap then check, and insert bootstrap and check again...